# Rails Regular Expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, rubular

I'm really new to regular expression. I have the following url: `http://www.foo.bar.com/hgur_300x300.jpg` and `http://www.foo.bar.com/hgur_100x100.jpg`

How would I use gsub with regular expression in rails to find [300X300.jpg AND 180X180.jpg] and replace it with 500X500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"http://www.foo.bar.com/hgur_100x100.jpg".gsub(/\d+/, "500")
```

will replace the two "100" with "500"

UPDATE:

```
"http://www.foo.bar.com/hgur_100x100.jpg".gsub(/\d+x\d+/, "500x500")
```

will be more precise

Comment: This solution assume that there is no other numbers in the link - otherwise, they will be replaced with 180 also.

Comment: Will any number be replace of just numbers in the format: [digit]x[digit]? Because I do usually have product numbers in my URL's however they are random and do not contain letters in them. eg:http://www.foo.bar.com/mp/00/76/30/38/41/0076303841848_P255045_300X300

Answer (score 0):

Please don't you a regular expression on the entire URL. URLs should be uniform, expressions can easily break them. You should split the path away from the rest of it first, then have a somewhat strict expression.

This code will use Rubys `uri` library to parse and then modify the path directly.

```
uri = URI.parse("http://www.foo.bar.com/hgur_300x300.jpg")
uri.path #=> "/hgur_300x300.jpg"
uri.path.gsub!(/\d{3}/, '500')
uri.to_s #=> "http://www.foo.bar.com/hgur_500x500.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following method.

If your URL is a pure string, then just `"my_url.com/hgur_100x100.jpg".gsub(/\d+x\d+/,"500x500")`.

This will match "100x100" and you replace it "500x500"

I'm suggesting this because if you just match using `\d+/`, you end up matching all numbers in the URL, including port numbers.

@injekt's method of using `URI.path` is pretty good. I've been using URI and I think it's a pretty solid module. But that is very dependent on you having well-formed URIs in the first place. For example, if you punch in a URL (e.g. a hand typed one `www.mydomain.com/image333.png` without a `scheme`, the `path` and `host` will be undefined too.

Comment: Another reason you shouldn't use an expression on the entire string and use something like the `uri` library instead

Comment: Yeap, I prefer using URI too. But even using URI, i think it's preferable to match "100x100" instead. I'm a little paranoid =)